# Xcode Unit Tests: Xcode doesn't stop at breakpoints

Tags: xcode, debugging, xctest

Using Xcode 6.3 Beta 2 with Units Tests I have the following problem:

When I do unit testing the breakpoints in the unit-test module work but the break codes in the code under test don't are ignored.

Any ideas?

Comment: While this is quite and old question, I am now having the same issue on XCode 6.3 (6D570) iOS SDK 8.3 released on 8/Apr/2015!!!! - it does not stop on any breakpoints at all and none of the solutions listed in other posts of SO resolve the issue

Comment: It works normally on newly created projects, so the issue seems to be with projects created on earlier versions of XCode ...

Comment: My xcode stops on test breakpoints, but blows up one second after..... :(

Comment: Have no such issue on Xcode 7+

Comment: @grep Did you ever manage to sort this?

Comment: I am getting this problem in case Testing project the breakpoints do not work. Do you guys got any solution.

Comment: Running into same problem. Any solution?

Comment: I still experience this issue at times with XCode 8.3.3. Restarting XCode can help. Sometimes setting a breakpoint on the first line of the method (on the method signature) can also help when a breakpoint within the body of the method does not work.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue and the reason was the scheme settings:

1.- Edit your scheme

2.- Choose "Test" in the left panel

3.- Check the "Debug executable" option

That was all.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simple point to check even if this post is quite old: Does your Test-Method start with the prefix "test"?

Omitting the prefix doesn't produce a warning and Xcode simply doesn't execute the method any more.

This can look like Xcode doesn't stop at your breakpoint - nevertheless Xcode doesn't execute the method at all!