# Logging and breakpoints not working in XCTests

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest

I have a large iOS project, and my problem is that, when running XCTests:

- Breakpoints within the app, or within the tests themselves, are not hit
- `NSLog`s/`print`s from within the app are not visible within the test log, but logs from within the tests *are* visible

I have another iOS project within the same workspace, and breakpoints and logging work fine.

The iOS project in question was originally created on an old version of Xcode (circa 2012, unsure which version exactly); and I have seen [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28962166/xcode-unit-tests-xcode-doesnt-stop-at-breakpoints#comment47267045_28962166) elsewhere from somebody having seen this issue with an old `.xcodeproj`.

The project itself is hybrid Obj-C/Swift, uses several Cocoapods, a watchkit extension, and tests divided into three targets.

Given my project's complicated configuration, I would prefer to avoid beginning again with a fresh `.xcodeproj` and try to mirror exactly the configuration of my faulty one.

What could the reason for this fault be and what might I change within my existing `.xcodeproj`'s configuration to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The culprit was `DEPLOYMENT_POSTPROCESSING = YES` in the project file.

Answer (score 9):

Select your scheme, go to *Edit scheme...* and tick the *Debug executable* option under the *Test* > *Info* pane.

The debugger will attach to both your tests and your target application, and breakpoints will be hit on both parts of your project.

Note that when a breakpoint is hit in your target application, your test is still running and may time out, killing both applications.

Comment: Yeah it's not that, already ticked.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

This has to do with how your test scheme is set up. I was having the same issue and I fixed mine by turning Debbuging "ON" for the test executable.

[image: Turn Debug executable to "ON"]

Answer (score 1):

I made a new scheme for my UI tests, so I assumed the debugger wasn't attaching to the new UI tests scheme when no breakpoints were hit. However, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922865/xcode-8-breakpoint-in-file-not-working/47285183)
had the correct answer for me.

> In my case breakpoint was not hit in just one callback, so I changed "Swift Compiler" "Optimization Level" to "No optimization" in project target build settings for debug, and it started working in Xcode 9.3 as well as AppCode.

Answer (score 1):

For breakpoint not working case check which Optimization Level you have, if you have the new -Os breakpoints start acting weird, change to `-None` or `No Optimization` in debug mode whatever option you have

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Problem with logs not appearing in a debug area, in my case, was due to the OS_ACTIVITY_MODE argument which was set to "disable" in Scheme -> Test -> Arguments

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything in the replies as of this date, but in the end the only thing that worked in my case was to remove the target and recreate it again.